# Question about Normal Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I am trying to show that the normal curvature of M in the direction of α′ is
equal to the normal component of acceleration. I know that if I start with $U\cdot \alpha'=0$ and derive that I end up with
\begin{align*}
U'\cdot \alpha' + U\cdot \alpha'' =0 
\end{align*}
And then I can subtract $U'\cdot \alpha'$ to the other side. But how is this related to the shape operator? I know $S(\alpha')=U\cdot \alpha'$, not $U'\cdot \alpha'$.
My goal is to somehow get to $S(\alpha')\cdot\alpha'$.

Comment: You’re assuming an arclength parametrization. Guess you haven’t looked at my text after all. What is the definition of the shape operator? Oh, and why does your product rule have a negative?

Comment: @TedShifrin Slowly reading your text. But am still confused how $U^{\prime}\cdot\alpha^{\prime}$ relates to the Shape operator. I'm defining the Shape operator as the negative directional derivative of the normal vector, $U$. I see your point about the minus in the product rule. I've edited the problem to update that. I was working backwards, hoping to eventually move $-U\cdot\alpha^{\prime\prime}$ to the other side, and conclude something about $U^{\prime}\cdot\alpha^{\prime}$ in relation to $S$.

Comment: If you understand what your $U’$ is, it’s precisely $-S(\alpha’)$.